# PHP MySQL update not execute if call twice in short time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter with MySQL. The case is, customer do shop, and pay with account.

Code as follow:

```
$globallockname = 'MEM_LOCK_ORDER_PAYLOCK';
//lock with memcache add
if (!$this->getGlobalLock($globallockname, 10)){
    dexit(array('error'=>true,'msg'=>'get loack failed'));
}

//check if account is enough
$member = $this->admin_model->getItem('member', array('id'=>$this->_member['id']), false);

if ($this->_member['account'] >= $amountpay){]
    //pay
    $this->admin_model->update('member', "`account` = `account` - ".$amountpay, "`id` = ".$this->_member['id']);
}else{
    //unlock
    $this->delGlobalLock($globallockname);
    dexit(array('error'=>true,'msg'=>'account is short, please recharge'));
}

//unlock
$this->delGlobalLock($globallockname);
```

When a customer clicks "buy" once, everything goes fine, but if they click "buy" twice in a short time, this script will execute twice, and the first update will not work.

I've checked the return of `$db->query`, each of them return true.

Comment: how short is the "short time"? Under a second? A few minutes?

Comment: @Simba, in 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: @ Shoyeb Sheikh, update the question with full code.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the same field twice. So you will get the last update only.
ie the first update is overwritten with second update..

hope this helps...

Comment: but i was update the field with adding its value, not with absolute number, so i suppose it should adding twice ,not overwritten it.

Answer (score 0):

once buy button is clicked, disable it and show with progressing caption. This will avoid further clicks.

Comment: actually i've disabled the button, the happened when customer click the button when its avaliable again.

Comment: Update should be an associative array . So it should be like this : $this->admin_model->update('member', array("`account` => `account` - ".$amountpay), "`id` = ".$this->_member['id']);  Ref: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::update

Comment: the update function will execute query script when param is not array.  code as follows:   public function update($db, $table, $data, $where)
    {
        if (empty($db) || empty($table)) {
            return false;
        }
        $db = $this->load->database($db, true);

        if (is_array($data)) {
            return $db->update($table, $data, $where);
        } else {
            return $db->query("UPDATE `" . $db->dbprefix($table) . "` SET {$data} WHERE {$where}");
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I did a stupid thing, there's nothing wrong with mysql or codeigniter. In my index controller, I go member member info and then set it again, so the memcache lock did not work, the information was overwrite...